# Groupby and apply a function

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, apply, pandas-groupby

I would like to groupby by the variable of my df "cod_id" and then apply this function:

```
[dd.loc[dd['dt_op'].between(d, d + pd.Timedelta(days = 7)), 'quantity'].sum() \
                        for d in data_1['dt_op']]
```

Moving from this df:

```
print(dd)
dt_op      quantity      cod_id
20/01/18      1            613
21/01/18      8            611
21/01/18      1            613 
...
```

To this one:

```
print(final_dd)
n = 7

dt_op      quantity   product_code     Final_Quantity
20/01/18      1            613               2
21/01/18      8            611               8
25/01/18      1            613               1
...
```

I tried with:

```
dd.groupby(['cod_id']).apply([dd.loc[dd['dt_op'].between(d, d + pd.Timedelta(days = 7)), 'quantity'].sum() \
                            for d in data_1['dt_op']])
```

But it raises:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a cumbersome but working solution:

```
def lookforward(x):
    L = [x.loc[x['dt_op'].between(row.dt_op, row.dt_op + pd.Timedelta(days=7)), \
         'quantity'].sum() for row in x.itertuples(index=False)]
    return pd.Series(L, index=x.index)

s = df.groupby('cod_id').apply(lookforward)
s.index = s.index.droplevel(0)

df['Final_Quantity'] = s

print(df)

       dt_op  quantity  cod_id  Final_Quantity
0 2018-01-20         1     613               2
1 2018-01-21         8     611               8
2 2018-01-21         1     613               1
```

Comment: It works, using: s = data.groupby('cod_id').apply(lookforward).T
    s= s.reset_index(drop=True) but it is extremely slow with the original dataset

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli, Yes, that's expected given your algorithm. You should look up `resample`.

Comment: The problem with it is that is aggregates the dataset

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli, Hmm, I can't think of a better answer. It's entirely up to you, but one idea is to ask a new question focusing only on performance, showing a solution that works. You may then get more appropriate responses.